# CSS - set input background by another div class

Tags: css

I have this simple form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

I need set background color when `form-group` has `input-group-addon`. in this example: first input has background color and last not.

This is my css:

```
.form-group:has(.input-group-addon) > input{
      background: yellow;
  }
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: `:has` is not yet supported by browsers... try `.form-group .input-group-addon > input`

Comment: also, even if `:has` were supported, `input` is not a direct child of `.form-group`, so the `>` combinator wouldn't match it

Comment: given that `input` is the following sibling of the `.input-group-addon`, I'd suggest the following selector: `.form-group .input-group-addon + input` (note the sibling combinator `+`, or possibly also `~`, instead of the child combinator `>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need this selector:

```
.form-group .input-group-addon + input{
  background: yellow;
}
```

**EDIT**: fixed the selector as mentioned by @Ilya

Comment: `input` is not a child of `.input-group-addon` in the example, so the selector won't work. I'd replace it with `.form-group .input-group-addon + input`

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to you can set the background color from jquery as well. 
You can do something like

```
if($('.form-group').find('input-group-addon').length !== 0) {
     $('.form-group').css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```